# Show that this piece-wise function defines a differentiable solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, proof-verification, functional-equations

Show that

$y(x) = \begin{cases}-x^4 & x < 0, \\ x^4 & x \geqq 0 \end{cases}$

defines a differentiable solution of $xy'=4y$ for all $x$, but is not of the form $y(x)=Cx^4$.

Comment: The function is I think obviously differentiable at any $x\ne 0$, and the derivative can be computed by the usual formula. For $x=0$ we show the derivative is $0$ by considering $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{y(h)-y(0)}{h}$. If $h\gt 0$ this is $h^3$, for $h\lt 0$ it is $-h^3$, so it has limit $0$ as $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your definition of y(x), we have that: 
$$y'(x):$$$$=-4x^3, x < 0$$ $$=4x^3, x \geq 0$$

substitute these values into $xy'=4y$

for $x<0$ you have $x(-4x^3)=4(-x^4)$ which reduces to $x^4=x^4$

you take the same steps to verify for $x>0$.

Comment: But, isn't that of the form $y(x)=Cx^4$, where $C=\pm1$? Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: There is no **single** $C$ such that $y(x)=Cx^4$. If you "solve" $xy'=4y$ carelessly by separation of variables, you will get the "result" that all solutions have shape $Cx^4$ for some number $C$. The point of the question/example is to warn against mechanical use of separation of variables. The reason for the breakdown is that when you write $\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{4}{x}$, you are dividing by $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I think you answered your own question here. This y is a particular solution that is not of the form $y=CX^4$  for any one choice of C. And you've shown the values C must take w.r.t. the value of x.

Comment: Andre has given a very good answer here. You would do well for yourself to make sure you understand his point.